# How to update an xml string into a database without changing from double quotes to single quotes?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-update, sqlclient

I need to update part of an xml string in a database, but I do not want to change from double quotes to single quotes, in other words, I want to preserve the double quotes in the xml string.  This question is based of another question I had found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9132443/33690)

The following:

```
ExecuteNonQuery("Update Logs 
                 SET Message = '" + encryptedMessage.Replace('"','\'') + "' 
                 WHERE ID = " + message.Id);
```

Will replace the double quotes with single quotes and save that to the db, but I do not want to permanently change the quotes.

I am trying this:

```
string sqlUpdate = "Update Logs SET Message = @Message where Id = @Id";
                SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("@Id", message.Id);
                SqlParameter msg = new SqlParameter("@Message", message.Msg);

                Collection parameters = new Collection();
                parameters.Add(id);
                parameters.Add(msg);

                Data.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlUpdate,parameters);
```

`Data.ExecuteNonQuery` already takes care of the connection for me.

I noticed the sql passed into the ExecuteNonQuery method is `Update Logs SET Message = @Message where Id = @Id`

I am just using Collection because this the method took a VBCollection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a parametrized query instead and pass in your XML as a `SqlParameter`:

```
string sqlUpdate = "Update Logs set Message = @MESSAGE where ID = @ID";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdate, someConnection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MESSAGE", SqlDbType.Xml)).Value = encryptedMessage;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = message.Id;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @Xaisoft: see [Introduction to Parametrization in SQL Server](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-parameterization-in-sql-server) for a great tutorial, and [Give me parametrized queries, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) by this site's co-founder, Jeff Atwood

Comment: Here's an [example using .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/parameterized-query-and-sql-injection-attacks/).